# Hide a checkbox if it contains the same data-name as clicked element

Tags: jquery

I have an image with a data-name and a checkbox with a matching data-name. If I click on the image, I want the matching checkbox to hide.

```
$( "body" ).on("click", "#dbpic", function() {
    var picName = $(this).data("name");
    $('input[name="pics[]"]:contains('+picName+')').hide();
```

I am trying to do it with "contains" but I don't think this is the right way to do it or rather I don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: use the `data-name` to select the matching checkbox: `$('input[data-name="' + picName + '"]').hide()`

Comment: @billyonecan, thank you. I am not able to test this right now but will post feedback as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select the name of the attribute you must use this syntax `input[attribute_name="name_value"]`. And in your case use this:

```
$('input[data-name="'+picName+'"]')
```

Here is a simple demo:

```js
$( "img" ).on("click", function() {
    var picName = $(this).data("name");
    $('input[data-name="'+picName+'"]').hide();
    
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img data-name="name" id="dbpic" src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Share/icon/color/Gaming//pokecoin1600.png" style="height:48px;width:48px">

<label><input type="checkbox" data-name="name"> To Hide</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" data-name="name2">Not to Hide</label>
```

[jQuery Selectors Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: Thank you. I am not able to test this right now but will post feedback as soon as possible.

Comment: @user8463989 welcome, waiting for your feedback :) Goodluck